# Highcharts 3D scatter points not showing names in tooltips

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I modified the example found [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-scatter-draggable) to add names to the data points but the tooltip is not showing the names. It shows the series name but not the point name:

```
 ---------
|o Points |
|x: 2     |
|y: -6    |
|z: 2     |
 ---------
```

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dn03h21h/1/). My series data is defined as:

```
series: [{
    name: "Points",
    data: [{
    color:"rgb(0,0,0)",
        x:5,
        y:-5,
        z:9,
        name:"Point 1"
    },{
        color:"rgb(0,0,0)",
        x:2,
        y:-6,
        z:2,
        name:"Point 2"
    },{
        color:"rgb(0,0,0)",
        x:7,
        y:6,
        z:8,
        name:"Point 3"
    }]
}]
```

I thought it should show the point name in the tooltip as shown in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/data-array-of-objects/) 2D example.Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Highcharts JS v4.0.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define your own [tooltip formatter](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/tooltip#formatter):

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function(chart) {
        var p = this.point;
        return p.name + '<br>' + 
               p.x + ', ' + p.y + ', ' + p.z;
    }
}
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/aLLj8j0m/2/